# Create custom slider to control 'scrollLeft' of html element using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a custom slider to emulate horizontal scroll behavior of a specific element. the slider is implemented as a stand alone component and the selector for the element is passed to the slider component as a property:

```
<template>
  <div class="slidercontainer">
    <h1>{{contentWidth}}</h1>
    <button class="right-scroll"></button>
    <input
      type="range"
      min="1"
      :max="contentWidth"
      value="1"
      class="slider"
      v-on:input="handleScroll"
    >
    <button class="left-scroll"></button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["el"],
  data() {
    return {
      scrollLeft: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll($event) {
      this.content.scrollLeft = this.contentWidth - $event.target.value;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    content() {
      return document.querySelector(this.el);
    },
    contentWidth() {
      return this.content.scrollWidth - this.content.clientWidth;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

the problem though, is that content wont update and always return 0. when first loaded the app is waiting for some data from the server and thats why when `mounted` the `contentWidth` equals 0, but i thought returning `content` as a computed property should take care of that, but nothing happens after the content is injected with some new...well - content :)
any idea how to solve this?